# AddBusinessDays and GetBusinessDays

Tags: c#, .net

I need to find 2 elegant complete implementations of

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime date, int days)
{
 // code here
}

and 

public static int GetBusinessDays(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
 // code here
}
```

O(1) preferable (no loops).

EDIT:
 By business days i mean working days (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday). No holidays, just weekends excluded.

I already have some ugly solutions that seem to work but i wonder if there are elegant ways to do this. Thanks

---

This is what i've written so far. It works in all cases and does negatives too.
Still need a GetBusinessDays implementation

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime startDate,
                                         int businessDays)
{
    int direction = Math.Sign(businessDays);
    if(direction == 1)
    {
        if(startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(2);
            businessDays = businessDays - 1;
        }
        else if(startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
            businessDays = businessDays - 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(-1);
            businessDays = businessDays + 1;
        }
        else if(startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(-2);
            businessDays = businessDays + 1;
        }
    }

    int initialDayOfWeek = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek;

    int weeksBase = Math.Abs(businessDays / 5);
    int addDays = Math.Abs(businessDays % 5);

    if((direction == 1 && addDays + initialDayOfWeek > 5) ||
         (direction == -1 && addDays >= initialDayOfWeek))
    {
        addDays += 2;
    }

    int totalDays = (weeksBase * 7) + addDays;
    return startDate.AddDays(totalDays * direction);
}
```

Comment: Are there elegant solutions when it comes to something as illogical as dates?

Comment: Are you conerned with Holidays? – James Conigliaro . No

Comment: With internationalization, this is difficult. As mentioned in other threads here on SOF, holidays differ from country to country certainly and even from province to province. Most governments do not schedule out their holidays more than five years or so.

Comment: Voting down people who are trying to help is not a winning strategy.

Comment: Can date, start or end be weekend days?

Comment: @Patrick I'm sure that's possible, but more importantly, what is the result of the calculation? E.g. what is Saturday + 0 days?

Comment: So does adding 1 business day to Saturday give you Monday or Tuesday? And what about 0 business days?

Comment: I can't understand why someone downvoted Ash: it's true that it's not an answer to what was asked, but Ash IS TOTALLY RIGHT, I have the very same issue: my software has to run in Europe (Mon-Sun) AND Africa/Asia (Sat-Fri). To downvote this, one has to be an ass (the animal, just in case) who can't see beyond his nose: it looks like there are people on SO who are afraid of knowledge, just don't want to know and prefer to remain on their reassuring ignorance: but they don't do a service to AZ in first place (and to themself too, but it's their own business)

Comment: Saturday + 1 should give Monday. + 0 should make no change even if Saturday

Comment: i (the OP) downvoted because i thought i made it clear in the question what are the constraints and it seemed Ash dind not pay attention. I apologize if that hurt someones feeling but is just a downvote

Comment: @AZ : Where in the original question did you mention internationalization constraints?

Comment: @AshMachine, exactly. He didn't.

Comment: Brief note about the `AddBusinessDays` implementation in the question above (which was actually a deleted answer I've proposed to undelete; a mod copied that answer to the question instead): In my opinion this solution is better than all answers so far because it's the only one that deals correctly with negative values, Saturday and Sunday as source and doesn't need a Third-Party lib. (I've made a little program to test the different solutions here.) I would only add `if (businessDays == 0) return startDate;` at the beginning of the method to get the correct result for this edge case as well.

Comment: @Slauma wow, that was 5 years ago!. time flies when you're having fun i guess. Thanks for the comment. It was me (the OP) that posted that answer and it was deleted because it was not fair at the time to answer your own question. Also i lacked a solution for the second method. The current accepted answer provided decent solutions for both (even if not perfect) so i accepted it at some point. Of coure if someone needs a copy in their own project they should test them first exhaustively.

Comment: actually i'm wrong. it seems someone else did the deletion and it was recent :).

Comment: @AZ.: The first deletion was quite old. After my request to undelete your answer a mod had undeleted the answer (for 30 seconds) to copy the content below your question and then he deleted it again. That's why your answer has this recent delete time stamp. I wrote the comment above because for my purpose your `AddBusinessDays` was the most general solution here that worked in all cases I need. I've copied it into one of my current projects (after slight modification and translation into C++), thanks for the code :) It helped a lot since it's surprisingly difficult to get all edge cases right.

Comment: Holidays differ from country to country, but this question has nothing to do with holidays. It has to do with weekends, which is clearly stated in problem description. This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Latest attempt for your first function:

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days)
{
    if (days < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("days cannot be negative", "days");
    }

    if (days == 0) return date;

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(2);
        days -= 1;
    }
    else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        days -= 1;
    }

    date = date.AddDays(days / 5 * 7);
    int extraDays = days % 5;

    if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5)
    {
        extraDays += 2;
    }

    return date.AddDays(extraDays);

}
```

The second function, GetBusinessDays, can be implemented as follows:

```
public static int GetBusinessDays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        start = start.AddDays(2);
    }
    else if (start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        start = start.AddDays(1);
    }

    if (end.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        end = end.AddDays(-1);
    }
    else if (end.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        end = end.AddDays(-2);
    }

    int diff = (int)end.Subtract(start).TotalDays;

    int result = diff / 7 * 5 + diff % 7;

    if (end.DayOfWeek < start.DayOfWeek)
    {
        return result - 2;
    }
    else{
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second one, one solution is to take the difference between date and date+days.  This is nice in that it guarantees that the two functions will sync properly, and it removes redundancy.

Comment: Feed current date, run for 0 to 10 business days, it always fail on Wednesday.

Comment: Yeah, we got there in the end. (I say 'we' for my tiny contribution!) Up-voted for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your input Noldorin, I can only upvote your comments unfortunately!

Comment: Haha, no worries. With the rep I currently have, it's of little consequence. Now, it would be interesting to see a similar implementation of `GetBusinessDays` (the approach should be similar conceptually) - might have a think later.

Comment: This didn't work for me when I converted it to VB.Net -- not sure if it's a bug in my conversion or the main logic, but I ran it on 10/1/09, adding 3 business days and it was giving me back 10/8/09 -- it should be giving me 10/6/09.

Comment: (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday==0.                                           So you need to define day of the week in that way:                                                              int dayOfWeek = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : (int)date.DayOfWeek;

Comment: dont understand the if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5)
    {
        extraDays += 2;
    } part... whats it for?

Comment: If the final day calculated is a Saturday or Sunday, it pushes the answer on to the following Monday or Tuesday respectively

Comment: DateTime.AddDays works with negative numbers. This does not correctly follow the same pattern as using negative numbers with AddBusinessDays allows non-business days to be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the -1.  The function was not designed to work with negative days. While I can see a valid reason the look for n business days in the future, I can see less reason to calculate n business days ago.

Comment: If I call GetBusinessDays on a consecutive Saturday / Sunday, e.g. 18/10/2014 and 19/10/2014 I get -3. However, it does seem to work for everything else, so just forcing negative numbers to 0 seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, GetBusinessDays seems to give an incorrect output when the weekend days are inside of the date range, and not the start or end date  07/12/2016 - 07/08/2016 = -4.however, it should equal -2

Comment: For the AddBusinessDays give 10 days to add from 24th Nov 18. this will return 13th Dec 18 which is incorrect. it should be 7th Dec 18.
Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{AddBusinessDays(new DateTime(2018, 11, 24), 10)}");` gives `07/12/2018 00:00:00` on my machine

Comment: I agree with @Ristogod. It is not the same pattern as DateTime.AddDays with negative numbers.

Answer (score 83):

using [Fluent DateTime](https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var dateTime1 = now.AddBusinessDays(3);
var dateTime2 = now.SubtractBusinessDays(5);
```

internal code is as follows

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given number of business days to the <see cref="DateTime"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The date to be changed.</param>
    /// <param name="days">Number of business days to be added.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DateTime"/> increased by a given number of business days.</returns>
    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime current, int days)
    {
        var sign = Math.Sign(days);
        var unsignedDays = Math.Abs(days);
        for (var i = 0; i < unsignedDays; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                current = current.AddDays(sign);
            }
            while (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
                current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        }
        return current;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts the given number of business days to the <see cref="DateTime"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The date to be changed.</param>
    /// <param name="days">Number of business days to be subtracted.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DateTime"/> increased by a given number of business days.</returns>
    public static DateTime SubtractBusinessDays(this DateTime current, int days)
    {
        return AddBusinessDays(current, -days);
    }
```

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked for me when converted to VB.Net

Comment: Here I am 14years late but in the case which the hours are important, this solution does not work properly if the current is in the weekend, ex: Friday 15:30 outputs tuesday 15h30 while Saturday 9:30 outputs tuesday 9:30.

Answer (score 15):

I created an extension that allows you to add or subtract business days.
Use a negative number of businessDays to subtract. I think it's quite an elegant solution. It seems to work in all cases.

```
namespace Extensions.DateTime
{
    public static class BusinessDays
    {
        public static System.DateTime AddBusinessDays(this System.DateTime source, int businessDays)
        {
            var dayOfWeek = businessDays < 0
                                ? ((int)source.DayOfWeek - 12) % 7
                                : ((int)source.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;

            switch (dayOfWeek)
            {
                case 6:
                    businessDays--;
                    break;
                case -6:
                    businessDays++;
                    break;
            }

            return source.AddDays(businessDays + ((businessDays + dayOfWeek) / 5) * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Extensions.DateTime;

namespace AddBusinessDaysTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(5).ToString();
            label2.Text = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(-36).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is questionable if the source date is a Saturday or Sunday. For example: Saturday + 1 business day results in Tuesday, where I'd rather expect Monday.

Comment: @Slauma: This is how most businesses in Canada operate. +1 business day = "next business day", which in case of Saturday is Tuesday. Monday would be "same business day".

Comment: @Slauma Program works as intended. Think about it logically. If something business related kicks off on Saturday, and you have to allow 1 business day for people to react during the span of said business day, would it make sense to tell them it must be done by Monday?!

Comment: I agree with @Slauma, this doesn't make sense, if I input Saturday, then for the next business day I expect it to output Monday, hence, the next closest business day. If I wanted Tuesday, then I would input 2 days.

Comment: @metabuddy I think you're both right, problem is asking for "next business day" is different than asking today + 1 business day.

Answer (score 9):

For me I had to have a solution that would skip weekends and go in either negative or positive.  My criteria was if it went forward and landed on a weekend it would need to advance to Monday.  If it was going back and landed on a weekend it would have to jump to Friday.

> For example:
>
> - Wednesday - 3 business days = Last Friday
> - Wednesday + 3 business days = Monday
> - Friday - 7 business days = Last Wednesday
> - Tuesday - 5 business days = Last Tuesday

Well you get the idea ;)

I ended up writing this extension class

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime date, int addDays)
    {
        while (addDays != 0)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(Math.Sign(addDays));
            if (MyClass.IsBusinessDay(date))
            {
                addDays = addDays - Math.Sign(addDays);
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
}
```

It uses this method I thought would be useful to use elsewhere...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static bool IsBusinessDay(DateTime date)
    {
        switch (date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to bother with that you can just replace out `if (MyClass.IsBusinessDay(date))` with if `if ((date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday) && (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday))`

So now you can do

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(-3);
```

or

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(5);
```

Here are the results from some testing:

```
Test                         Expected   Result
Wednesday -4 business days   Thursday   Thursday
Wednesday -3 business days   Friday     Friday
Wednesday +3 business days   Monday     Monday
Friday -7 business days      Wednesday  Wednesday
Tuesday -5 business days     Tuesday    Tuesday
Friday +1 business days      Monday     Monday
Saturday +1 business days    Monday     Monday
Sunday -1 business days      Friday     Friday
Monday -1 business days      Friday     Friday
Monday +1 business days      Tuesday    Tuesday
Monday +0 business days      Monday     Monday
```

Comment: I made the 2nd method an extension method as well:

        public static bool IsBusinessDay(this DateTime date)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime date, int days)
{
    date = date.AddDays((days / 5) * 7);

    int remainder = days % 5;

    switch (date.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            if (remainder > 3) date = date.AddDays(2);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            if (remainder > 2) date = date.AddDays(2);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            if (remainder > 1) date = date.AddDays(2);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            if (remainder > 0) date = date.AddDays(2);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            if (days > 0) date = date.AddDays((remainder == 0) ? 2 : 1);
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            if (days > 0) date = date.AddDays((remainder == 0) ? 1 : 0);
            break;
        default:  // monday
            break;
    }

    return date.AddDays(remainder);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am resurrecting this post because today I had to find a way to exclude not only *Saturday* and *Sunday* weekdays but also holidays. More specifically, I needed to handle various sets of possible holidays, including:

- country-invariant holidays (at least for the Western countries - such as January, 01).
- calculated holidays (such as Easter and Easter monday).
- country-specific holidays (such as the Italian liberation day or the United States ID4).
- town-specific holidays (such as the Rome St. Patron Day).
- any other custom-made holiday (such as "tomorrow our office wil be closed").

Eventually, I came out with the following set of helper/extensions classes: although they aren't blatantly elegant, as they do make a massive use of unefficient loops, they are decent enough to solve my issues for good. I'm dropping the whole source code here in this post, hoping it will be useful to someone else as well.

**Source code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper/extension class for manipulating date and time values.
/// </summary>
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the absolute year difference between two dates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt1"></param>
    /// <param name="dt2"></param>
    /// <returns>A whole number representing the number of full years between the specified dates.</returns>
    public static int Years(DateTime dt1,DateTime dt2)
    {
        return Months(dt1,dt2)/12;
        //if (dt2<dt1)
        //{
        //    DateTime dt0=dt1;
        //    dt1=dt2;
        //    dt2=dt0;
        //}

        //int diff=dt2.Year-dt1.Year;
        //int m1=dt1.Month;
        //int m2=dt2.Month;
        //if (m2>m1) return diff;
        //if (m2==m1 && dt2.Day>=dt1.Day) return diff;
        //return (diff-1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the absolute year difference between two dates.
    /// Alternative, stand-alone version (without other DateTimeUtil dependency nesting required)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="end"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int Years2(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return (end.Year - start.Year - 1) +
            (((end.Month > start.Month) ||
            ((end.Month == start.Month) && (end.Day >= start.Day))) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the absolute month difference between two dates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt1"></param>
    /// <param name="dt2"></param>
    /// <returns>A whole number representing the number of full months between the specified dates.</returns>
    public static int Months(DateTime dt1,DateTime dt2)
    {
        if (dt2<dt1)
        {
            DateTime dt0=dt1;
            dt1=dt2;
            dt2=dt0;
        }

        dt2=dt2.AddDays(-(dt1.Day-1));
        return (dt2.Year-dt1.Year)*12+(dt2.Month-dt1.Month);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the higher of the two date time values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt1">The first of the two <c>DateTime</c> values to compare.</param>
    /// <param name="dt2">The second of the two <c>DateTime</c> values to compare.</param>
    /// <returns><c>dt1</c> or <c>dt2</c>, whichever is higher.</returns>
    public static DateTime Max(DateTime dt1,DateTime dt2)
    {
        return (dt2>dt1?dt2:dt1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the lower of the two date time values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt1">The first of the two <c>DateTime</c> values to compare.</param>
    /// <param name="dt2">The second of the two <c>DateTime</c> values to compare.</param>
    /// <returns><c>dt1</c> or <c>dt2</c>, whichever is lower.</returns>
    public static DateTime Min(DateTime dt1,DateTime dt2)
    {
        return (dt2<dt1?dt2:dt1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given number of business days to the <see cref="DateTime"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The date to be changed.</param>
    /// <param name="days">Number of business days to be added.</param>
    /// <param name="holidays">An optional list of holiday (non-business) days to consider.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DateTime"/> increased by a given number of business days.</returns>
    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(
        this DateTime current, 
        int days, 
        IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays = null)
    {
        var sign = Math.Sign(days);
        var unsignedDays = Math.Abs(days);
        for (var i = 0; i < unsignedDays; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                current = current.AddDays(sign);
            }
            while (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
                || current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
                || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(current.Date))
                );
        }
        return current;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts the given number of business days to the <see cref="DateTime"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">The date to be changed.</param>
    /// <param name="days">Number of business days to be subtracted.</param>
    /// <param name="holidays">An optional list of holiday (non-business) days to consider.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="DateTime"/> increased by a given number of business days.</returns>
    public static DateTime SubtractBusinessDays(
        this DateTime current, 
        int days,
        IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        return AddBusinessDays(current, -days, holidays);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the number of business days from two dates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">The inclusive start date</param>
    /// <param name="endDate">The inclusive end date</param>
    /// <param name="holidays">An optional list of holiday (non-business) days to consider.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetBusinessDays(
        this DateTime startDate, 
        DateTime endDate,
        IEnumerable<DateTime> holidays)
    {
        if (startDate > endDate)
            throw new NotSupportedException("ERROR: [startDate] cannot be greater than [endDate].");

        int cnt = 0;
        for (var current = startDate; current < endDate; current = current.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
                || current.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
                || (holidays != null && holidays.Contains(current.Date))
                )
            {
                // skip holiday
            }
            else cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate Easter Sunday for any given year.
    /// src.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510411/1233379
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="year">The year to calcolate Easter against.</param>
    /// <returns>a DateTime object containing the Easter month and day for the given year</returns>
    public static DateTime GetEasterSunday(int year)
    {
        int day = 0;
        int month = 0;

        int g = year % 19;
        int c = year / 100;
        int h = (c - (int)(c / 4) - (int)((8 * c + 13) / 25) + 19 * g + 15) % 30;
        int i = h - (int)(h / 28) * (1 - (int)(h / 28) * (int)(29 / (h + 1)) * (int)((21 - g) / 11));

        day = i - ((year + (int)(year / 4) + i + 2 - c + (int)(c / 4)) % 7) + 28;
        month = 3;

        if (day > 31)
        {
            month++;
            day -= 31;
        }

        return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve holidays for given years
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="years">an array of years to retrieve the holidays</param>
    /// <param name="countryCode">a country two letter ISO (ex.: "IT") to add the holidays specific for that country</param>
    /// <param name="cityName">a city name to add the holidays specific for that city</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHolidays(IEnumerable<int> years, string countryCode = null, string cityName = null)
    {
        var lst = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach (var year in years.Distinct())
        {
            lst.AddRange(new[] {
                new DateTime(year, 1, 1),       // 1 gennaio (capodanno)
                new DateTime(year, 1, 6),       // 6 gennaio (epifania)
                new DateTime(year, 5, 1),       // 1 maggio (lavoro)
                new DateTime(year, 8, 15),      // 15 agosto (ferragosto)
                new DateTime(year, 11, 1),      // 1 novembre (ognissanti)
                new DateTime(year, 12, 8),      // 8 dicembre (immacolata concezione)
                new DateTime(year, 12, 25),     // 25 dicembre (natale)
                new DateTime(year, 12, 26)      // 26 dicembre (s. stefano)
            });

            // add easter sunday (pasqua) and monday (pasquetta)
            var easterDate = GetEasterSunday(year);
            lst.Add(easterDate);
            lst.Add(easterDate.AddDays(1));

            // country-specific holidays
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode))
            {
                switch (countryCode.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "IT":
                        lst.Add(new DateTime(year, 4, 25));     // 25 aprile (liberazione)
                        break;
                    case "US":
                        lst.Add(new DateTime(year, 7, 4));     // 4 luglio (Independence Day)
                        break;

                    // todo: add other countries

                    case default:
                        // unsupported country: do nothing
                        break;
                }
            }

            // city-specific holidays
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cityName))
            {
                switch (cityName)
                {
                    case "Rome":
                    case "Roma":
                        lst.Add(new DateTime(year, 6, 29));  // 29 giugno (s. pietro e paolo)
                        break;
                    case "Milano":
                    case "Milan":
                        lst.Add(new DateTime(year, 12, 7));  // 7 dicembre (s. ambrogio)
                        break;

                    // todo: add other cities

                    default:
                        // unsupported city: do nothing
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

**Usage info**

The code is quite self-explanatory, however here's a couple examples to explain how you can use it.

Add 10 business days (skipping only saturday and sunday week days)

```
var dtResult = DateTimeUtil.AddBusinessDays(srcDate, 10);
```

Add 10 business days (skipping saturday, sunday and all country-invariant holidays for 2019)

```
var dtResult = DateTimeUtil.AddBusinessDays(srcDate, 10, GetHolidays(2019));
```

Add 10 business days (skipping saturday, sunday and all italian holidays for 2019)

```
var dtResult = DateTimeUtil.AddBusinessDays(srcDate, 10, GetHolidays(2019, "IT"));
```

Add 10 business days (skipping saturday, sunday, all italian holidays and the Rome-specific holidays for 2019)

```
var dtResult = DateTimeUtil.AddBusinessDays(srcDate, 10, GetHolidays(2019, "IT", "Rome"));
```

The above functions and code examples are further explained [in this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/datetime-add-subtract-calculate-get-business-days-asp-net-c-sharp-helper-class-function/) of my blog.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to have those calls access a database table that defines the calendar for your business. You could code it for a Monday to Friday workweek without too much difficult but handling holidays would be a challenge.

Edited to add non-elegant and non-tested partial solution:

```
public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime date, int days)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < days; index++)
    {
        switch (date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                date = date.AddDays(3);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                date = date.AddDays(2);
                break;
            default:
                date = date.AddDays(1);
                break;
         }
    }
    return date;
}
```

Also I violated the no loops requirement.

Comment: I don't think the Saturday case would ever be hit.

Comment: @Dennis -- it would if the date passed in is a Saturday.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your code in order to make it work. Please test code prior to posting it next time, thank you.

Comment: And I thought the zero upvotes spoke for itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming late for the answer, but I made a little library with all the customization needed to do simple operations on working days... I leave it here : [Working Days Management](https://github.com/Opturne/WorkingDaysManagement)

Comment: Unfortunately this is GNU licenced so is "legal poison" for any commercial app.   Any chance you'd relax this to "MIT" or "Apache"?

Comment: Some static lists should probably be arrays (rather than linked lists).

Comment: I just changed the license to MIT (I do not want to block anything on something that simple). I will look into your other proposition.

Comment: Nice, it would be interesting to see working day management by country as some countries may have other working days than Monday to Friday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fluent DateTime library easily. Please refer to this Github library repository. https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(5);
```

You can consider weekdays as `BusinessDays`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days)
    {
        if (days == 0) return date;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < days)
        {
            if (!(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||  date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)) i++;  
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: in the future add a bit more context for answer and maybe why you've put what you have :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an "AddBusinessDays" that supported negative numbers of days to add, and I ended up with this:

```
// 0 == Monday, 6 == Sunday
private static int epochDayToDayOfWeek0Based(long epochDay) {
    return (int)Math.floorMod(epochDay + 3, 7);
}

public static int daysBetween(long fromEpochDay, long toEpochDay) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates
    final int fromDOW = epochDayToDayOfWeek0Based(fromEpochDay);
    final int toDOW = epochDayToDayOfWeek0Based(toEpochDay);
    long calcBusinessDays = ((toEpochDay - fromEpochDay) * 5 + (toDOW - fromDOW) * 2) / 7;

    if (toDOW   == 6) calcBusinessDays -= 1;
    if (fromDOW == 6) calcBusinessDays += 1;
    return (int)calcBusinessDays;
}

public static long addDays(long epochDay, int n) {
    // https://alecpojidaev.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/work-days-calculation-with-c/
    // NB: in .NET, Sunday == 0, but in our code Monday == 0
    final int dow = (epochDayToDayOfWeek0Based(epochDay) + 1) % 7;
    final int wds = n + (dow == 0 ? 1 : dow); // Adjusted number of working days to add, given that we now start from the immediately preceding Sunday
    final int wends = n < 0 ? ((wds - 5) / 5) * 2
                            : (wds / 5) * 2 - (wds % 5 == 0 ? 2 : 0);
    return epochDay - dow + // Find the immediately preceding Sunday
           wds +            // Add computed working days
           wends;           // Add weekends that occur within each complete working week
}
```

No loop required, so it should be reasonably fast even for "big" additions.

It works with days expressed as a number of calendar days since the epoch, since that's exposed by the new JDK8 LocalDate class and I was working in Java. Should be simple to adapt to other settings though.

The fundamental properties are that `addDays` always returns a weekday, and that for all `d` and `n`, `daysBetween(d, addDays(d, n)) == n`

Note that theoretically speaking adding 0 days and subtracting 0 days should be different operations (if your date is a Sunday, adding 0 days should take you to Monday, and subtracting 0 days should take you to Friday). Since there's no such thing as negative 0 (outside of floating point!), I've chosen to interpret an argument n=0 as meaning *add* zero days.

Answer (score 0):

**I believe this could be a simpler way to GetBusinessDays:**

```
    public int GetBusinessDays(DateTime start, DateTime end, params DateTime[] bankHolidays)
    {
        int tld = (int)((end - start).TotalDays) + 1; //including end day
        int not_buss_day = 2 * (tld / 7); //Saturday and Sunday
        int rest = tld % 7; //rest.

        if (rest > 0)
        {
            int tmp = (int)start.DayOfWeek - 1 + rest;
            if (tmp == 6 || start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) not_buss_day++; else if (tmp > 6) not_buss_day += 2;
        }

        foreach (DateTime bankHoliday in bankHolidays)
        {
            DateTime bh = bankHoliday.Date;
            if (!(bh.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || bh.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) && (start <= bh && bh <= end))
            {
                not_buss_day++;
            }
        }
        return tld - not_buss_day;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code with both departure date, and delivery date at customer.

```
            // Calculate departure date
            TimeSpan DeliveryTime = new TimeSpan(14, 30, 0); 
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            if (dt.TimeOfDay > DeliveryTime) dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            dt = dt.Date + DeliveryTime;
            string DepartureDay = "today at "+dt.ToString("HH:mm");
            if (dt.Day!=DateTime.Now.Day)
            {
                DepartureDay = dt.ToString("dddd at HH:mm", new CultureInfo(WebContextState.CurrentUICulture));
            }
            Return DepartureDay;

            // Caclulate delivery date
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            string DeliveryDay = dt.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo(WebContextState.CurrentUICulture));
            return DeliveryDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DateTime AddWorkingDays(this DateTime date, int daysToAdd)
{
    while (daysToAdd > 0)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);

        if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            daysToAdd -= 1;
        }
    }

    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetBusinessDays(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(0, (end- start).Days)
                                .Select(a => start.AddDays(a))
                                .Where(a => a.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                .Where(a => a.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                                .Count();
    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this solution is slightly different (has some good and bad points):

1. Solves weekends depending on the country (i.e. Arab countries have Friday-Saturday weekends)
2. Depends on external library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Date/
3. Only deals with adding business days
4. Skips holidays as well (this can be removed)
5. Uses recursion

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(this DateTime date, int days, CountryCode countryCode)
    {
        if (days < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("days cannot be negative", "days");
        }

        if (days == 0)
        {
            return date;
        }

        date = date.AddDays(1);

        if (DateSystem.IsWeekend(date, countryCode) || DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(date, countryCode))
        {
            return date.AddBusinessDays(days, countryCode);
        }

        days -= 1;

        return date.AddBusinessDays(days, countryCode);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BusinessDaysTests
{
    [TestCase("2021-06-04", 5, "2021-06-11", Nager.Date.CountryCode.GB)]
    [TestCase("2021-06-04", 6, "2021-06-14", Nager.Date.CountryCode.GB)]
    [TestCase("2021-05-28", 6, "2021-06-08", Nager.Date.CountryCode.GB)] // UK holidays 2021-05-31
    [TestCase("2021-06-01", 3, "2021-06-06", Nager.Date.CountryCode.KW)] // Friday-Saturday weekend in Kuwait
    public void AddTests(DateTime initDate, int delayDays, DateTime expectedDate, Nager.Date.CountryCode countryCode)
    {
        var outputDate = initDate.AddBusinessDays(delayDays, countryCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedDate, outputDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps someone.

```
private DateTime AddWorkingDays(DateTime addToDate, int numberofDays)
    {
        addToDate= addToDate.AddDays(numberofDays);
        while (addToDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || addToDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            addToDate= addToDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        return addToDate;
    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. In most cases it will not work. Unlikely to help anyone.