# Determine the length of a season with conditions (ex. winter snow season)

Tags: r, time-series

I want to determine the length of the snow season in the following data frame:

```
DATE    SNOW
1998-11-01  0
1998-11-02  0
1998-11-03  0.9
1998-11-04  1
1998-11-05  0
1998-11-06  1
1998-11-07  0.6
1998-11-08  1
1998-11-09  2
1998-11-10  2
1998-11-11  2.5
1998-11-12  3
1998-11-13  6.5
1999-01-01  15
1999-01-02  15
1999-01-03  19
1999-01-04  18
1999-01-05  17
1999-01-06  17
1999-01-07  17
1999-01-08  17
1999-01-09  16
1999-03-01  6
1999-03-02  5
1999-03-03  5
1999-03-04  5
1999-03-05  5
1999-03-06  2
1999-03-07  2
1999-03-08  1.6
1999-03-09  1.2
1999-03-10  1
1999-03-11  0.6
1999-03-12  0
1999-03-13  1
```

Snow season is defined by a snow depth (SNOW) of more than 1 cm for at least 10 consecutive days (so if there is snow one day in November but after it melts and depth is < 1 cm we consider the season not started).

My idea would be to determine:

1) the date of snowpack establishement (in my example 1998-11-08)

2) the date of "disappearing" (here 1999-03-11)

3) calculate the length of the period (nb of days between 1998-11-05 and 1999-03-11)

For the 3rd step I can easily get the number between 2 dates using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666172/calculating-number-of-days-between-2-columns-of-dates-in-data-frame).

But how to define the dates with conditions?

Comment: what are the rules to find 'snowpack establishment' and 'disappearing'. Is it something trivial I'm not seeing? There are other zeros and why 0.6?

Comment: I'm looking for the first date where there is >= 1 cm for at least 10 consecutive days (beginning of snow season) and then the first date where snow < 1 cm (end of snow season).

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks! It should be there with your question. Add it to your text.

Comment: but it was... I tried to explained it by another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
# copy data from clipboard
d <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE)
# coerce DATE to Date type, add event grouping variable that numbers the groups
# sequentially and has NA for values not in events.
d <- transform(d, DATE=as.Date(DATE),
                  event=with(rle(d$SNOW >= 1), rep(replace(ave(values, values, FUN=seq), !values, NA), lengths)))
# aggregate event lengths in days
event.days <- aggregate(DATE ~ event, data=d, function(x) as.numeric(max(x) - min(x), units='days'))
# get those events greater than 10 days
subset(event.days, DATE > 10)
#   event DATE
# 3     3  122
```

You can also use the event grouping variable to find the start dates:

```
starts <- aggregate(DATE ~ event, data=d, FUN=head, 1)
# 1     1 1998-11-04
# 2     2 1998-11-06
# 3     3 1998-11-08
# 4     4 1999-03-13
```

And then merge this with `event.days`:

```
merge(event.days, starts, by='event')
#   event DATE.x     DATE.y
# 1     1      0 1998-11-04
# 2     2      0 1998-11-06
# 3     3    122 1998-11-08
# 4     4      0 1999-03-13
```

Comment: Ok thanks, not very intuitive (for me) but apparently it's working... Any idea to get the dates (beginning and end of season)?

Comment: And to get the date of the end of the season: DATE.y + DATE.x (in fact DAT.x is the length of the snow period meeting conditions of >= 10 cm of snow for at least 10 consecutive days).

Comment: by the way, what is the "1" in the aggregate of starts?

Comment: it's the argument to `head`, saying give me the first element.