# How to count the number of days between each day in R

Tags: r, date

Given Date in date frame:

```
Date: Note it's in year/month/day format
2020-01-01      
2020-02-01  
2020-03-03      
2020-04-04
```

How do I get the aggregate count total of number of days between each date.

```
Count: 
0
30
58
87
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Calculating number of days between 2 columns of dates in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666172/calculating-number-of-days-between-2-columns-of-dates-in-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the character strings to a `Date` object.

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-03", "2020-04-04"))
dates - dates[1]
# Time differences in days
# [1]  0 31 62 94
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your character strings to date format using `as.Date` and then use the `lag` function:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-04-04"))

df$ndays <- as.numeric(as.Date(df$date) - dplyr::lag(as.Date(df$date), n = 1, default = as.Date(df$date)[1]))

> df
        date ndays
1 2020-01-01     0
2 2020-02-02    32
3 2020-03-03    30
4 2020-04-04    32
```