# R Package bizdays Giving Unexpected Results

Tags: r, calendar, date-arithmetic, bizdays

I'm attempting to use the bizdays  R package in order to calculate the number of business days in the week excluding weekends and holidays.

Below I have a simple examples that evaluates the number of business days between 12/24/2018 and 12/28/2018 with the 24th and the 25th as holidays.

I would anticipate the bizdays functions to return 3 days (26th, 27th and 28th), however it is returning 2 days.

What confuses me even more is if I call `is.bizday` for each of the five weekdays within that week I get 3 TRUE and 2 FALSE (what I would expect).

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

If this is working as intended, is there a good work around for getting all days inclusive between two dates?

Code is below:

```
> library(bizdays)
> 
> holidays<-as.Date(c("2018-12-24", "2018-12-25"))
> 
> calfr<-as.Date("2018-01-01")
> calto<-as.Date("2018-12-31")
> 
> fr<-as.Date("2018-12-24")
> to<-as.Date("2018-12-28")
> 
> 
> cal <- create.calendar('mycal',holidays=holidays, weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"), start.date = calfr, end.date = calto)
> 
> bizdays(fr,to,cal)
[1] 2
> 
> is.bizday(c('2018-12-24','2018-12-25','2018-12-26','2018-12-27','2018-12-28'), cal)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

edit:

I found an answer that does not involve the bizdays package at [Calculating Business Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556247/calculating-business-days).

I'm leaving the original question up, as the bizdays package has an incredible amount of potential, and i'm still curious as to why it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the option `financial=FALSE` inside `create.calendar` function to add 1 day to every calculation:

```
cal <- create.calendar('mycal', holidays=holidays, weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"), start.date = calfr, end.date = calto,
    financial=FALSE)
```