# Count of days between 2 dates excluding the weekend in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate number of days between two dates by excluding the weekends.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fgsk.jpg)

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the number of weekdays between 2 dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046708/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-2-dates-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a sequence of dates (and days, both with `lubrirdate`), filter out the weekends and count the number of rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(date = seq(ymd("2018-06-01"), ymd("2018-09-30"), by = "days"))

days <- mutate(df, day = wday(date, label = T)) %>%
  filter(day != "Sat", day != "Sun") %>%
  nrow()
```

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what you want, with a reproducible example, what you have tried and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the help i actually figured out a solution using 'bizdays' package this helped me in excluding the weekends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of library chron 
Sample Code:

```
library(chron)
number_of_days <- (START_DATE,END_DATE,by=1)

length(number_of_days)
length(number_of_days[!is.weekend(number_of_days)])
```

Hope this helps