# How to ignore empty cells or NA when operating on values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the number of weekdays between two dates in a data frame.

I am using the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046708/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-2-dates-in-r). The solution works when dates are available in all columns, but if any dates are missing, then there are no results.

Here is the code being used:

```
library(dplyr)

# The macro to calculate working days
Nweekdays <- Vectorize(function(a, b)
  sum(!weekdays(seq(a, b, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")))

# Sample data frame
id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3") 
startDate = c("2019-08-01", "2019-08-06", "2019-08-10") 
endDate = c("2019-08-05", "2019-08-15", "2019-08-20")
df = data.frame(id, startDate, endDate)

# Using dplyr to coerce to Date and run macro
df <- df %>%
  mutate(startDate = as.Date(startDate)) %>% 
  mutate(endDate = as.Date(endDate)) %>% 
  mutate(workingdays = Nweekdays(startDate, endDate))
```

The code works correctly and gives me a new column with working days. But if one of the dates is missing or NA, e.g.

```
startDate = c("2019-08-01", "", "2019-08-10")
```

then I get

```
Evaluation error: 'to' must be a finite number.
```

and there is no new column generated. I want an empty result for the missing value, but the correct result for all others. I am sure I am missing something basic so apologies for that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your function to deal with non-date values so it only tries to compute if both a and b are dates:

```
Nweekdays <- Vectorize(function(a, b) {
  if (!is.na(a) & !is.na(b)) {
    sum(!weekdays(seq(a, b, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"))
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
})
```

you can use some more strict form of validation rather than `!is.na()` with something like `lubridate::is.Date()`, but this is a base solution and any non-date value will convert to NA when you call `as.Date()` in the mutate line.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. :-)