# R - exclude weekends from time interval calculations with lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I wish to calculate the intervals between dates. The differences in days should take  weekends in account. I have over 200 dates stamps.

For example, the currently displayed time difference between 5th (Tuesday) and 11th (Monday) January are 5 days. I would like to obtain 3 days.

I could manage to get to a solution without excluding Saturday and Sunday with the following code and the packages `lubridate` and `dplyr`.

Could you please guide me how to exclude the weekends for calculation?
Thank you.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


dates <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-11", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-14", "2021-01-18", "2021-01-25", "2021-01-29")

d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dates, as.data.frame))

dateoverview <- rename(d, Dates = 1)

dateoverview$Dates <- lubridate::ymd(dateoverview$Dates)

datecalculation <- dateoverview %>%
                   mutate(Days = Dates - lag(Dates)) %>% 
                   mutate(Weekday = wday(Dates, label = FALSE))

datecalculation


##         Dates    Days Weekday
## 1  2021-01-01 NA days       6
## 2  2021-01-04  3 days       2
## 3  2021-01-05  1 days       3
## 4  2021-01-06  1 days       4
## 5  2021-01-11  5 days       2
## 6  2021-01-13  2 days       4
## 7  2021-01-14  1 days       5
## 8  2021-01-18  4 days       2
## 9  2021-01-25  7 days       2
## 10 2021-01-29  4 days       6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the number of weekdays between 2 dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046708/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-2-dates-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, there is a function somewhere already doing this but here is a custom one which can help you calculate date difference excluding weekends.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

date_diff_excluding_wekeends <- function(x, y) {
  if(is.na(x) || is.na(y)) return(NA)
  sum(!format(seq(x, y - 1, by = '1 day'), '%u') %in% 6:7)
}

datecalculation %>%
  mutate(Days = map2_dbl(lag(Dates), Dates, date_diff_excluding_wekeends))

#        Dates Days Weekday
#1  2021-01-01   NA       6
#2  2021-01-04    1       2
#3  2021-01-05    1       3
#4  2021-01-06    1       4
#5  2021-01-11    3       2
#6  2021-01-13    2       4
#7  2021-01-14    1       5
#8  2021-01-18    2       2
#9  2021-01-25    5       2
#10 2021-01-29    4       6
```

- `seq(x, y - 1, by = '1 day')` creates a sequence of dates between previous date and current date - 1.
- `format(..., "%u")` returns day of the week. 1 is for Monday, 7 for Sunday.
- Using `sum(!format(...) %in% 6:7)` we count number of days that are present on weekdays.

Comment: I want to push this comment again. Just to make sure you have seen it. If you have seen it already and would prefer me to ask a new question, please just tell me. Not a problem at all. I am aware that usually I should open a new question, but based on your very customized code I ask here in the comment section. Is there any possibility to exclude specific days? For example, I assume the 12th of January is like weekend and therefore exclude this date, so the difference between 11th and 13th is only 1 day instead of 2. Thank you once again!

Comment: Hi @17757970 , sorry I missed your earlier comment. Please ask this as a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
library(lubridate)

# sample data
df = data.frame(Dates = seq(ymd('2021-01-01'),ymd('2021-12-31'),by='days'))
df_weekdays = df %>% filter(!(weekdays(as.Date(df$Dates)) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')))

#Application to your data 
datecalculation =   datecalculation %>% 
    filter(!(weekdays(as.Date(datecalculation$Dates)) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')))
```