# How to get weekends between two dates?

Tags: c#, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate the number of weekdays between two dates in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820173/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-c)

Is there a method to know how much saturdays and sundays there are between two dates?
for example: 13/01/2011 to 28/02/2011
result will be: 3 saturdays and 3 sundays

can someone help please?
thank you in advance

Comment: Refer to [How to calculate num of weekdays between 2 dates](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/44982/how-to-calculate-num-of-weekdays-between-2-dates.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820173/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-c - Dublicate

Comment: Your result is incorrect. Between the two dates you posted, there are 7 weekends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could traverse through days between the two dates and for each day check it against saturday and sunday. `Datetime` conains `DayOfWeek`.