# Code to calculate no.of days between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

C# Code to calculate no.of days between two dates...I have start date in one textbox and end date in another textbox and i need to get no. of days between the two dates and to be displayed in third textbox and it should exclude holidays and weekends(saturday and sunday).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Comment: where is the list of holidays?

Comment: Do you want to use a calendar to look up if a day is a holiday? For example in a Christian calendar _Good Friday_ may be a holiday even if it's not a Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the textbox dates to date time object and then try something on the following lines.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 03, 01);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today; // 12 March 2013
int totalDays = 0;
while (startDate <= endDate)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
        || startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
        continue;
    }
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    totalDays++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total days excluding weekends: {0}", totalDays);
```

Comment: If you want to count all days including weekends I wouldn't want to use this. This should only be used when you don't want to include the weekends.

Comment: @albertjan, yes otherwise `TimeSpan.TotalDays` property is enough for calculating difference between two dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var dateDiff = FirstDate - SecondDate; 
 double totalDays = dateDiff.TotalDays;
```

Comment: this will not exclude the weekends

Answer (score 1):

if you have two dates in textboxes viz textBox1 and textBox2

```
DateTime date1= new DateTime();
DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
double days;

bool isDate1Valid =DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out date1);
bool isDate2Valid =DateTime.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out date2);

if(isDate1Valid && isDate2Valid)
days = (date1-date2).TotalDays;
```

**Edit**

If you need to do it *without looping*, [Here is how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820173/calculate-the-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-c-sharp).

If date difference is too large, looping may consume some amount of extra time.

Comment: `it should exclude holidays and weekends(saturday and sunday).` that is n the question. TotalDays will not exclude that

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
    DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("somedate");
    DateTime enddate = DateTime.Parse("somedate");
    int daycount = 0;
    while (startdate < enddate)
    {
        startdate = startdate.AddDays(1); // Fixed
        int DayNumInWeek = (int)startdate.DayOfWeek;
        if (DayNumInWeek != 0)
        {
            if (DayNumInWeek != 6)
            { daycount += 1; }
        }
    }
```