# LINQ - how to get next three business days excluding dates in table?

Tags: linq

I need to find the next three available business days for a scheduling application. What is available depends upon excluded dates in a table. So...as long as the date is not in my table and not a Saturday or Sunday, I want the next three. I'd like to find an efficient way of doing this.

I need to return a `List<DateTime>`. The table is simple - ExcludedDates has an ID and a DateTime with the excluded date.

I'd like to have a single LINQ query expression but can't figure it out...thanks to all in advance and I apologize if this is trivial or obvious - it isn't to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this purely with linq because of the weekend exclusion requirement. You have might to run this in a limited loop checking each week until you have gathered three open days.

Comment: Take a look at this post. It has the weekend part of what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Comment: And to extend on that, you could get your list of excluded dates and do another `.Where(d => !dateList.Contains(d))` (or something like that...) and then a `.Take(3)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this...

```
  DateTime start = DateTime.Now.Date;
  var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 10) // make this '10' higher if necessary (I assume you only exclude non-workingdays like Christmas and Easter)
                    .Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset))
                    .Where(date => !( date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Sunday))
                    .Where(d=> !exceptionTable.Any(date => date == d))
                    .Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks like it may work for me. However, the second .Where() is throwing me. Any() uses the values from my exception table as input for the lambda, but I don't know how to access the dates generated toward the beginning in the predicate. The d var in the code does not reference anything (The name "d" does not exist in the current context). Sorry again for the noob questions, but I can't quite get this figured out :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the 'd =>' part

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that a month will be reasonable depending on your excluded dates.

```
        DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
        // first generate all dates in the month of 'date'
        var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)).Select(n => new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, n));
        // then filter the only the start of weeks
        var results = (from d in dates
                       where d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && !excludes.Any(i => i.DateTime.Date == d.Date) && date < d
                       select d).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> result = (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, excludeTable.Rows.Count + 6)
        let date = inputDate.AddDays(i)
        where date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
              date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
              !excludeTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => (DateTime) r["ExcludeDate"]).Contains(date)
        select date).Take(3).ToList();
```

`excludeTable.Rows.Count + 6` is to cover the worst case where you skip over every thing in the excludeTable and then you have to skip over another weekend.

Answer (score 0):

```
var excludedList = new List<long>() { DateTime.Parse("2011-07-27").Ticks };

var week = new List<long>(){
                DateTime.Now.Date.Ticks, 
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(3).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(4).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(6).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(7).Ticks,
                DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(8).Ticks
            };

var available = (from d in week.Except(excludedList)
                 where new DateTime(d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && new DateTime(d).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                 select new DateTime(d)).Take(3);

foreach (var a in available)
     Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
```