# To get the count of working days between two date in linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can i get the count of working days between two dates in linq. 
if i am giving like 1/1/2014(LeaveFrom)  to  3/1/2014( LeaveTo) , i need to get the answer like '3'.
I tried like

```
NoofDays=  Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (LA.LeaveTo).Subtract(LA.LeaveFrom).Days)
                                         .Select(offset => (LA.LeaveFrom).AddDays(offset)).Count()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the number of business days between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: I work 7 days a week. Do you mean week days?

Comment: Why cant u use timespan. you will get the result.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + something).Select(whatever).Count()` is just a complicated way of writing `something`. Why do you think you need Linq?

Comment: @Henrik Actually, it's the equivalent of `1 + something` (the second parameter of `Range` is the count, not the end value). Presumably 1/1/2014 to 1/1/2014 is considered 1 day of leave, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're counting every day as a working day, your code already works. Abbreviating things a bit you've got:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (to - from).Days)
    .Select(offset =>(from).AddDays(offset)).Count()
```

but the `Select` is redundant as you're only doing a `Count` afterwards anyway, so:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (to - from).Days).Count()
```

but all you're doing here is counting the numbers the `Range(int start, int count)` function has generated, so all the enumeration was pointless because you've specified this count in the first place, i.e.

```
1 + (to - from).Days
```

However, the enumeration would be useful if you wanted to exclude weekends etc. using some to-be-defined function, e.g.

```
Func<DateTime, bool> isWorkDay = x => 
{
    if(x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) return false;
    if(x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) return false;
    if(x.Day == 25 && x.Month == 12) return false;
    // etc.
    return true;
};

Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (to - from).Days)
    .Where(x => isWorkDay(from.AddDays(x))).Count()
```

Comment: You're better off not hardcoding your holiday exceptions, since not every holiday is pinned to a specific date (Easter varies each year).

Comment: Indeed. That comes under `// etc.` :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use TimeSpan instead. It is easy to get your desired result.

```
DateTime LeaveFrom= DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
DateTime LeaveTo = DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
 TimeSpan dtspan = LeaveTo- LeaveFrom;    
 double diff=  dtspan.TotalDays;
```