# Get days of week between two selected dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two `datetimepickers`. So I want to get the days of the week between the selected values.

Example: `date1 = 14/1/2015` and `date2 = 17/1/2015`

So the result should be: `days = Wed. Thu. Fri. Sat.`

Comment: Can I ask what you tried? Can you please share your effort so we can see what you tried, this will help us see where things are going wrong so we can help you better. As it stands, it reads like: "do my work for me" which may not be well received. You can [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27938399/edit)

Comment: days of week == 7 days per week OR workdays (i.e. no sunday, no saturday)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your problem can be easily solved by just simple loop from date1 to date2

Comment: There is an answer in stackoverflow for this :)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I did some coding, but all what I got is calculating the number of days only.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I did some coding, but all what I got is calculating the number of days only.

Comment: @Danil The linked provided doesnt meet my request. That provides the days number between two dates.

Comment: Where is John, offering is awesome library JodaTime? :)

Comment: What if the date range is bigger (i.e. more than a week)? Do you want each `DayOfWeek` once, or do you want to be able to tell for example how many wednesdays are in between the two dates?

Comment: @Corak If the date is more than one week, the result will be one week and 2 days (for example) or it can be two weeks and 3 days. 
2 weeks and Sat. Sun. Mon.

Comment: @OJazem - So you want one entry for every actual day. Later, when you're working with that sequence of `DayOfWeek` items, do you want to be able to tell the actual date again?

Comment: @Corak Actually I want to get all the selected days in a variable and number of weeks in another variable. no need to tell the actual date of each day (if u mean that). the selected date is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily iterate your `DateTime` values like;

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 14);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 17);
while (dt2 >= dt1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.DayOfWeek);
    dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);
}
```

Result will be;

```
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

If you wanna their [abbreviated day names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as `Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat`, you can use [`"ddd"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dddSpecifier) with a *english-based* culture (like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) like;

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 14);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 17);
while (dt2 >= dt1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("ddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 6):

You want to get the `DayOfWeek`s of all `DateTime`s between two dates?

```
int daysDiff = (date2 - date1).Days;
List<DayOfWeek> days = Enumerable.Range(0, daysDiff + 1) // +1 because you want to include start and end date
    .Select(d => date1.AddDays(d).DayOfWeek)
    .ToList();
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, which includes non-usual use of a for-loop and the `yield return` statement:

```
void Main()
{
    var daysOfWeek = DaysBetween(
        new DateTime(2015, 1, 14), 
        new DateTime(2015, 1, 17));

    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Join(", ", daysOfWeek.Select(d => d.ToString().Substring(0, 3))));

    // prints: Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
}

IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> DaysBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    for (var dateTime = start; dateTime <= end; dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1))
    {
        yield return dateTime.DayOfWeek;
    }
}
```