# Is there an optimized way of getting business weeks between two dates?

Tags: c#, linq, date

Just wondering if there is a more optimized and/or neater way (using LINQ for example) of writing what I have below to get a list of business week date ranges between two dates?

This is what I have currently ..

```
// Some storage
public class Bucket
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

// Other code removed for brevity ...

DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 7, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2015, 9, 1);

DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday;

var buckets = new List<Bucket>();
var currentDate = start;
DateTime startOfBucket = currentDate;
DateTime endOfBucket = currentDate;
while (currentDate <= end)
{
    var currentDayOfWeek = currentDate.DayOfWeek;

    // Skip days outside the business week
    if (currentDayOfWeek >= firstDayOfWeek && currentDayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeek)
    {
        if (currentDayOfWeek == firstDayOfWeek)
        {
            // Start a new bucket
            startOfBucket = currentDate;
        }

        if ((currentDayOfWeek == lastDayOfWeek) || (currentDate == end))
        {
            // End of bucket
            endOfBucket = currentDate;

            // Create bucket
            buckets.Add(new Bucket() 
            { 
                StartDate = startOfBucket, 
                EndDate = endOfBucket 
            });

        }
    }

    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

And this will give me the following date ranges ...

- Start: 01/Jul/2015   End: 03/Jul/2015
- Start: 06/Jul/2015   End: 10/Jul/2015
- Start: 13/Jul/2015   End: 17/Jul/2015
- Start: 20/Jul/2015   End: 24/Jul/2015
- Start: 27/Jul/2015   End: 31/Jul/2015
- Start: 03/Aug/2015   End: 07/Aug/2015
- Start: 10/Aug/2015   End: 14/Aug/2015
- Start: 17/Aug/2015   End: 21/Aug/2015
- Start: 24/Aug/2015   End: 28/Aug/2015
- Start: 31/Aug/2015   End: 01/Sep/2015

N.B. The first and last weeks are purposefully not full weeks (they abide to the date range given).

**Edit**
The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates) gives the number of days between the two dates but I am interested in getting the collection of date ranges.

Also, I don't need to account for any holidays.

Thanks,

Comment: What would you want to do about public holidays? Cultures where the working week isn't always Monday to Friday?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @serhiyb I especially like the answer by José Silva

Comment: @RoyT. his answer still iterates over each day, while accepted/upvoted answer does provide answer in O(1).

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon .. this is a basic range so not taking into account any holidays. Thanks

Comment: @serhiyb that solution just gives the number of days. I'm interested in getting the individual date ranges.

Comment: @GavinSutherland see the answer on that same question by José Silva ;). Thats why I said I liked that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite handy using linq

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 1);
var workDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
    .Where(date => (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    .Select(i => i);


var display = workDates
    .GroupAdjacentBy((x, y) => x.AddDays(1) == y)
    .Select(g => string.Format("Start: {0:dd/MMM/yyyy} End: {1:dd/MMM/yyyy}", g.First(), g.Last()));
```

With the extension method `GroupAdjacentBy<T>`

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                var pred = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                    {
                        list.Add(e.Current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                    }
                    pred = e.Current;
                }
                yield return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/79hfvn)

Comment: Thanks @Eric I like this solution. I added the extension in above as it took my a minute to realize it was not a .Net extension.

Comment: @GavinSutherland Let me add to the answer for others

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [Eric's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402216/787157) so please give him any upvote. I've just modified his solution to handle business weeks that could be 7 days long and also for one that could wrap a weekend.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 1);

DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday;

var workDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1)
            .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
            .Where(date => 
                // Normal work weeks where first day of week is before last (numerically) e.g. Monday -> Friday or Sunday -> Saturday
                (firstDayOfWeek < lastDayOfWeek && date.DayOfWeek >= firstDayOfWeek && date.DayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeek) ||
                // Cater for business weeks whose start and end dates wrap over the weekend e.g. Thursday -> Tuesday
                (lastDayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek && (date.DayOfWeek >= firstDayOfWeek || date.DayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeek)))
            .Select(i => i);

var display = workDates
            .GroupAdjacentBy((x, y) => x.AddDays(1) == y && !(x.DayOfWeek == lastDayOfWeek && y.DayOfWeek == firstDayOfWeek))
            .Select(g => string.Format("Start: {0:dd/MMM/yyyy} End: {1:dd/MMM/yyyy}", g.First(), g.Last()));
```