# How to return a list of weekend dates between 2 dates

Tags: c#, datetime

At the moment I have this code to return a table of all dates between 2 dates. How could I change this to have it only return the weekend dates.
The purpose of this is to use the weekend dates to check against column headers in a DataGridView to "grey-out" the weekends. I hope that's clear.

```
static public List<string> GetDates(DateTime start_date, DateTime end_date)
{
    List<string> days_list = new List<string>();

    for (DateTime date = start_date; date <= end_date; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        days_list.Add(date.ToShortDateString());
    }

    return days_list;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx

```
static public List<string> GetDates(DateTime start_date, DateTime end_date)
    {
        List<string> days_list = new List<string>();
         for (DateTime date = start_date; date <= end_date; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                 days_list.Add(date.ToShortDateString());
        }

        return days_list;
```

Comment: Brilliant, completely missed this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can create range of dates and then filter on them using `DayOfWeek` as @Vitor said:

```
static public List<DateTime> GetWeekendDates(DateTime start_date, DateTime end_date)
{
 return Enumerable.Range(0, (int)((end_date- start_date).TotalDays) + 1)
                  .Select(n => StartDate.AddDays(n))
                  .Where(x=>x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
                         || x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hope this solution will help you

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2011,3,1);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
int days = diff.Days;
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
{
    var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
    switch (testDate.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToShortDateString());
            break;
    }
}
```

in above code I am finding Saturday and Sunday between 1st March 2011 and today. So I have taken two variables called startDate and endDate. After that I have got difference between them and then via for loop I am checking that day of week is Saturday or Sunday

Comment: What does this code do? And why should it help him?