# How to calculate time between dates on a report viewer expression

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I have a program that uses report viewers to show various types of data to the user, and I need one of them to (basically) calculate the days between two dates WITHOUT weekends (i.e: from Friday to Monday, should show 2 and not 4).

So far, I can calculate it but with the weekends.

If anyone knows how, I'll appreciate it.

Code sample:(the formula i use on one of my tables as a expression)

```
CInt(Avg(DateDiff(dateinterval.DayOfYear, 
                  Fields!DataEntregue.Value, 
                  Fields!DataPrevista.Value, 
                  FirstDayofWeek.Monday)))
```

Comment: Verdolino: Thanks for the edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates), I have converted Alec Pojidaev's (not accepted) answer to VB. I also returned an integer instead of double:

```
Public Shared Function GetBusinessDays(startD As DateTime, endD As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim calcBusinessDays As Double = 1 + ((endD - startD).TotalDays * 5 - (startD.DayOfWeek - endD.DayOfWeek) * 2) / 7
    If CInt(endD.DayOfWeek) = 6 Then
        calcBusinessDays -= 1
    End If
    If CInt(startD.DayOfWeek) = 0 Then
        calcBusinessDays -= 1
    End If
    Return CInt(calcBusinessDays)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
GetBusinessDays(date1, date2)
```

BTW, in the future, what you were looking for was *how to calculate number of business days between two dates in [enter language here]*. A quick web search for this would have brought you to a number of answers.

Comment: 1º: I did made a search on the web for this, couldn't find anything that would fit in my case
2º: i used the tags to tell which language i am using

Comment: Also, i kinda need to use this on an expression, so the "usage" part doesnt fit. but i'll try to adapt. thx!

Comment: Leo, I searched for answers in C#, because there are a lot more people using that language. This is why I had to convert to VB. I usually have more luck searching for C# answers, even though I write mostly VB. Good luck!

Comment: Need to check my data, but it seems to work fine. I would upvote u if i could, so .... +1

Comment: Great! You should be able to mark completed at least ... :)