# Calculate StartDate when End Date & back days given

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, date

I am developing c#.net solution where i have to calculate Start Date based on provided End date and Duration (back days) without weekends.

i.e. End Date: 05/5/2011 
     Back days: 5

Start Date = (05/5/2011) - 5 days (Excludes weekends)

Start Date = 29/04/2011

thanks you,

Comment: See `AddBusinessDays()` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/add-business-days-and-getbusinessdays/1044821#1044821) and do `AddBusinessDays(endDate, -5)` or use [Fluent DateTime](http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/) which has a similar method and a lot more in it.

Comment: To clarify (05/5/2011) - 5 = (28/04/2011), right? not 29/04/2011. Want to make sure if this is a requirement or a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is probably what I'd do:

```
DateTime CalcStartDate(DateTime endTime, int daysBack)
{
    DateTime startTime = endTime.Date;

    while (daysBack > 0)
    {
        startTime = startTime.AddDays(-1);
        if (startTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && startTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            --daysBack;
        }
    }

    return startTime;
}
```

Or even better, Bala's suggestion of using a library. Date and time is messy, a hardened/tested library is usually a good choice.

Comment: Thanks all for sharing their idea about the issue

Comment: I tried this and it's works for me.. public DateTime CalcStartDate(DateTime EndDate, int daysBack)
        {
            DateTime StartDate = EndDate;

            for (int i = 1; i < daysBack; i++)
            {
                if (StartDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(-3);  
                }
                else
                {
                    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(-1);
                }
                
            }
           return StartDate;
       }

Answer (score 0):

Bala R has the answer correctly.  Here is a link to an article on how to use the AddBusinessDays() method:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AddBusinessDay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how far back you are going to go. If it is a lot of days back then looping through the days might be a little CPU intensive. Well, probably not with modern processors...

I decided to implement a solution without a loop.
My code is a little more difficult to read, but it should be more efficient performance-wise.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime SubtractBusinessDays(this DateTime fromDateTime, int days)
    {
        var subtractDays = days % 5;
        var dayNumber = fromDateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : (int)fromDateTime.DayOfWeek;
        var addDays = Math.Max(dayNumber - 5, 0);
        var result = fromDateTime.AddDays(addDays - subtractDays - (days / 5 * 7));
        if ((addDays + dayNumber) % 7 <= subtractDays)
            result = result.AddDays(-2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for sharing your idea on this issue.. I taken bit of logic from Matt's answer and rewrite as below which meet my requirement..