# Calculate shipping date on working days

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Basically I have 3 products on my online store. The specifics of each are stored in a List aray. However

- product 1 ships in 3 working days
- Product 2 ships the very next working day
- Product 3 takes 7 working days to ship

How would I calculate the `Estimated date` of arrival **ETDA** (excluding saturday and sunday) to find out when the product arrives.

**Example :** Customer orders product 1, The day when order is placed is Thursday, so product 1 takes 3 working days to ship, in other words it will arrive on Tuesday. How would I perform this in c# showing the user it will be arriving on Tuesday.

Comment: What data store are you using ? SQL, xml, hard coded?

Comment: it is hard coded currently

Comment: If product 1 takes 3 working days to ship, and the customer orders it on a Thursday, then it should SHIP on Tuesday.  When it would arrive is a whole other story.

Comment: getting business days has a nice implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/add-business-days-and-getbusinessdays

Comment: Why not just give the user the tracking code from the shipping agent? I don't think your company can guarantee what happens to a package once it leaves, right?

Answer (score 3):

I would be tempted to do a brute force approach, just because it saves on brain power:

```
int workingDays = 3;//get from item
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today();
while(workingDays > 0)
{
    dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    if(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        workingDays--;
}
//dt is now the correct day
```

Comment: A google search saves on brain power: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/add-business-days-and-getbusinessdays

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: true, but I still prefer mine. It's much shorter, and the performance is going to be minor. Unless you start doing huge amounts of business days, but that would be silly

Comment: mine is also probably better suited to allow dynamically determining what days are classed as business days

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
public DateTime DayOfArrival(DateTime startDate, int numberOfWordkingDays )
{
    var result = startDate;
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < numberOfWordkingDays)
    {
        if (result.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && result.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            counter++;
        result = result.AddDays(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```