# how to exclude Saturday and Sunday from startDate and endDate datetime objects

Tags: c#, datetime

Developing in c#.I have two DateTime objects. I have to eliminate the Saturday and Sunday from the days count. Lets suppose I have 5 daysincluding Saturday and Sunday. I want to check the days for Saturday Sunday and reduces the days count.

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
 days = diff.Days;
```

I have tried this,

[How can I calculate the Number of Weekends between two dates](https://forums.asp.net/t/1142378.aspx?How%20can%20I%20calculate%20the%20Number%20of%20Weekends%20between%20two%20dates)

but i am unable to eliminate saturday sunday as the given link only eliminate the weekends if the dates difference is greater than 7. Haven't got my solution yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the number of business days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Are you excluding holidays?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66432/find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates-inclusively

Comment: excluding means I want to reduce days count if the day is a holiday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple loop between the days of the two dates and using `DayOfWeek` for checking if the day is a Saturday or Sunday?

Something like below should work:

```
int weekendDays = 0;

for(DateTime date = startDate; date.Date <= endDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if ((date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    {
        weekendDays++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful statement @Adriani

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin proposed [this edit](https://i.imgur.com/rfl1eFS.png) but I'm pretty sure his changes would not produce the right result.

Comment: nice answer but why the extra brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You cold use the following:

```
int daycount = 0;
while (startDate < endDate) 
{
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
    int DayNumInWeek = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek;
    if (DayNumInWeek != 0 && DayNumInWeek != 6)
         daycount += 1;       
}
```

Check [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48adadb4-f105-433c-a377-7de756cc3f73/duration-calculation-but-excluding-weekends?forum=csharpgeneral) or [This link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66432/find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates-inclusively) for more info and options.

Also duplicate of [Calculate the number of business days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617049/calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates)
, which has a nice LINQ approach by Alpha

To get a better performance and readability, you could implement [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044821/8242325).