# How to ignore weekends in date calculation

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any way to ignore weekends easily during date calculation like the microsoft project does, rather using hard code to skip the days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddBusinessDays and GetBusinessDays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044688/addbusinessdays-and-getbusinessdays)

Comment: Could you please share what exactly you are trying to implement, it would be great if you could include a few snippets regarding your current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Fluent DateTime library easily.
Please refer to this Github library repository.
https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(5);
```

You can consider weekdays as `BusinessDays`