# Count days minus weekends

Tags: php

I have a form that allows a user to enter the length of an event using 2 jquery date pickers which are then stored in a database using date.

I then return the number of days the event lasts for but I need to exclude weekends.

For example if an event lasts from Mon - Mon the result returned would be 6.

Here is how I'm currently returning the number of days from 2 date ranges:

```
<?=(($currentCourseDates)?ceil((strtotime($currentCourseDates[0]['enddate']." 00:00:00") - strtotime($currentCourseDates[0]['startdate']." 00:00:00")) / 86400)+1:0)?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279296/adding-days-to-a-date-but-excluding-weekends?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions here: [Calculate business days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days)  for php, using arrays, recursion, numbering